# Any way to change WP-PostRatings so you can only vote up?

Tags: plugins, plugin-wp-postratings

I'm using the up/down voting feature of this plugin and would like to not allow people to 'down vote'. So basically, if they like the post, they vote it up, and if not, they leave it how it is.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just gave a quick look at the plugin and in my opinion it would be easier to tweak the way you use it rather than to tweak the code itself. What you want is basically already existing in the '**Rationg options**', it's the **heart** option that only allow the user to do a like, or 'up vote', which is just the same. You then just have to change the picture of the heart  for the arrow one and then have a look at the 'Ratings template' to achieve what you need.